# styled function doesn't apply styling to components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

This is my first time working with `styled-components` and `material-ui`.

I was asked to refactor the Hook-Api approach to [Styled Components API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api) since other sections of the codebase already used this.

I have two separate branches, one with my original approach and one using the `styled` function.

The `styled` function approach doesn't work (styles aren't applied). I am not sure what I am missing (no errors and it appears all of my custom styles are loaded in their own style tags after the default Material UI themes). Here is some of my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, SyntheticEvent } from 'react'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import {
  Avatar,
  Button,
  CssBaseline,
  TextField,
  Link,
  Paper,
  Box,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  styled,
} from '@material-ui/core'

import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined'
import ErrorOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ErrorOutline'
import withLayout from 'withLayout'
import { UserContext } from 'context/userContext'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
// note: a palette object is defined, there aren't any errors related
// to the palette object references
const ContainerStyled = styled(Grid)({
  height: '100vh',
  color: palette.secondary.dark,
})

const AvatarStyled = styled(Avatar)({
  margin: '8px',
  backgroundColor: palette.secondary.main,
})
const BackgroundImageStyled = styled(Grid)({
  backgroundImage: 'url("/logo_horizontal_white.svg")',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
  backgroundSize: '80%',
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
})

const TypographyStyled = styled(Typography)({
  color: palette.secondary.dark,
})

const TextFieldStyled = styled(TextField)({
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
    borderColor: palette.primary.dark,
  },
  '& .MuiInputLabel-outlined.Mui-focused': {
    color: palette.secondary.dark,
  },
})

const LinkStyled = styled(Link)({
  // color: palette.secondary.dark,
  color: 'green',
})

const Login: NextPage = () => {
  // note: some code was removed here, none of it was related
  // to the styling

  const classes = {
    form: {
      width: '100%',
      // marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
      marginTop: '8px',
    },
    paper: {
      // margin: (8, 4),
      margin: '64px 32px',
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
  }

  return (
    <ContainerStyled container="true" component="main">
      <CssBaseline />
      <BackgroundImageStyled item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} />
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <AvatarStyled>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </AvatarStyled>
          <TypographyStyled variant="h5">Sign in</TypographyStyled>
          {loginState.error && (
            <LoginErrorMessage code={loginState.error.response?.status} />
          )}
          <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={loginHandler} noValidate>
            <TextFieldStyled
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="login-email-input"
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoFocus
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <TextFieldStyled
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              className={classes.submit}
              disabled={loginState.loading}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item>
                <LinkStyled
                  href="#"
                  variant="body2"
                >
                  {"Don't have an account? Request it"}
                </LinkStyled>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Box mt={5}>
              <Copyright />
            </Box>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </ContainerStyled>
```

Does anyone know why the Styled components aren't receiving their defined styles?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to help here. But noticed that you are using Next.js right? So one thing is to make sure you added the right settings like in this example [material-ui with next.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)

Also why don't you try `makeStyles` and `createStyles` like this

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
containerStyled:{
 height: '100vh',
  color: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
}
  })
);
const ContainerStyled=({children}:{children:JSX.Element}):JSX.Element=>{
 return   <Grid classeName={classes.containerStyled} >
      {children}
     </Grid>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at this [example](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#examples-4) you can pass to the returning styled function another function instead of an object, which takes an object with theme property.

this way for example, your `TypographyStyled` would look like:

```
const TypographyStyled = styled(Typography)(({ theme: { palette } }) => ({
  color: palette.secondary.dark,
}))
```